# AdMob doesnt show up in my SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I tried to implement a banner with AdMob into my SpriteKit Game. I added a banner in the GameViewController.swift just like shown in the code underneath, but the banner doesn't show up in my simulator.

What am I missing? I am using Swift 4.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var banner:GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
            banner.adUnitID = "here is my unit ID -> copy paste so cant be wrong"
            banner.rootViewController = self
            let req:GADRequest = GADRequest()
            banner.load(req)

            banner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height - banner.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
            view.addSubview(banner)
        }
    }
```

Comment: check that the banner.frame.size doesn't have 0 width and height.  The example I found for admob banners adds constraints manually, rather than just setting the frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to declare your ViewController as it conforms to GADBannerViewDelegate

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
```

can you try again after conforming to the protocol?

Comment: I added the GADBannerViewDelegate and set banner.delegate = self -> now it works thank you :)